# Extending a module that extends a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

Is there a way to "flatten" nested modules so that all of their methods can be used when extending another class or module?  For example:

```
class User
  extend UserStats
end

module UserStats

  module Current
    def active
      where('status = "active"')
    end
  end

end
```

I want to be able to extend UserStats (or User) such that the methods in UserStats::Current are available as class methods for User.

I tried "extend Current" in UserStats, but that doesn't seem to work.  Is there any way to do this?

Comment: When you say "doesn't seem to work", what do you mean? Can you give us an example of how you're trying to use this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not just `extend UserStats::Current` ?

Comment: Actually this will be fine.  The example for my situation is kind of a metaprogramming rat's nest, so instead of spelling it out I'm going to re-edit to the original question and mark this as the answer.  Thanks and my apologies.

Comment: No need to apologise – I hear this is a place for learning and discussion!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
module UserStats

  def self.extended(klass)
    klass.send(:extend, Current)
  end

  module Current
    def active
      puts "test"
    end
  end

end

class User
  extend ::UserStats
end

puts User.active
```